# Django Nginx Docker Gunicorn cant reach

Tags: django, docker, nginx, gunicorn

Sorry if it the answer seems obvious, but I've been bashing my head for the past couple of hours.

I've been following multiple tutorials trying to dockerize my application. No matter what combination of url:port or just url I tried I can't access the pages.

I have zero clue what am I doing wrong. I am assuming the following:

- NGINX config plain wrong. How can `upstream web` know what's `web`? I assume docker exposes it, but unsure whether this is correct.
- web container not exposing address and port properly?

I tried multipled settings, but non work.

I have the following:

`Dockerfile`

```
FROM python:3
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
RUN mkdir /code
WORKDIR /code
ADD requirements.txt /code/
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
ADD . /code/
ADD ./django.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

#COPY ./django.conf /etc/nginx/sites-available/
#RUN ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/django.conf /etc/nginx/sites-enabled
```

`docker-compose.yml`

```
version: '3'

services:
  db:
    image: postgres:9.6
    ports:
     - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=random_user
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=random_password
  redis:
    restart: always
    image: redis:4.0
    expose:
      - "6379"

  nginx:
    image: nginx:1.14.0
    container_name: nginx01
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    volumes:
      - ./code
    depends_on:
     - web
  web:
    build: .
    container_name: backend-api
    command: bash -c "python manage.py migrate && python manage.py collectstatic --noinput && gunicorn ops4_backend.wsgi -b 0.0.0.0:8000"
    depends_on:
      - db
    volumes:
      - ./code
    expose:
      - "8000"
    restart: always
```

`django.conf`

```
upstream web {
   ip_hash;
   server web:8000;
 }

 # portal
 server {
   location / {
        proxy_pass http://web:8000;
     }
   listen 8000;
   server_name localhost;

   location /static {
     autoindex on;
     alias /src/static/;
   }
 }
```

`docker ps -a`
[image: docker ps -a]

Comment: Try to change `"8000:8000"` in nginx `ports` of `docker-compose.yml` section to `80:8000`.

Comment: @JonhyBeebop if I do that I get `ERROR: for nginx  Cannot start service nginx: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint nginx01  Error starting userland proxy: mkdir /port/tcp:0.0.0.0:80:tcp:172.19.0.5:8000: input/output error`

Comment: @JonhyBeebop okay - restarted everything - now I'm getting 502 bad gateway with this. How to proceed further?

Comment: Try to look inside your nginx container and try to find your `django.conf`. You can go inside container using this  `docker exec -t -i container_name /bin/bash`. I think the answerer Roman is right and you do not have `django.conf` in your nginx container. And now it works because it use default nginx conf.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was doing almost the same task yesterday, and the only valuable difference I see is that you include `django.conf` in Django container, not in nginx one. I have following volume in `nginx` section of `docker-compose.yml`:
  `- ./nginx:/etc/nginx/conf.d`  (where `./nginx` is the folder with `django.conf`)

EDIT: here is my `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3'

services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "80:8000"
    volumes:
      - ./nginx:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - ./static_cdn:/static
    depends_on:
      - web
  db:
    image: postgres
    restart: always
  web:
    build: .
    restart: always
    command: bash -c "python3 manage.py makemigrations && python3 manage.py migrate && python3 manage.py collectstatic --no-input && gunicorn core.wsgi -b 0.0.0.0:8000"
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    expose:
      - "8000"
    depends_on:
      - db
```

`django.conf`:

```
upstream web {
    ip_hash;
    server web:8000;
}

server {
    location /static/ {
        alias /static/;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://web/;
    }
    listen 8000;
    server_name localhost;
}
```

With this setup nginx is available at `127.0.0.1:80` or just `127.0.0.1` as 80 is default http port.

Comment: I have just done this - now I'm seeing logs from nginx01, but I'm also seeing 502 bad gateway on the localhost:800 and still no response on 0.0.0.0:8000. Is there anything else seemingly different than from your setup?

Comment: says - page cannot be reached @JonhyBeebop

Comment: @BorkoKovacev edited my post, added `docker-compose.yml`

Comment: @BorkoKovacev edited again, added `django.conf`. Note proxy_pass string: you pass port twice in your config (in upstream and proxy_pass sections), I don't. Maybe it is the cause of bad gateway

Answer (score 0):

There are so many wrong things, please use [this](https://github.com/django-leonardo/django-leonardo/blob/master/docker-compose.yml) configuration. and then change it step by step toward your specific needs.

also checkout this page that talks about [Nginx Docker Configurations](https://docs.docker.com/samples/library/nginx/#complex-configuration) because one of your main problems is that you are not exposing django nginx conf that you make:

```
ADD ./django.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
```

to `nginx` container.
so `nginx` does not know how to map your configs.

Comment: If you could elaborate on what those wrong things are instead of just posting a link - I'd be grateful, so that I can learn where I went wrong. If you read my question carefully I said that I was following multiple tutorials, out of which I cannot grasp which way is the right way of doing things the proper docker way and that I am unsure why **my specific adjustment** of nginx is not working as intended.